# Java (How to add a decimal within an output)

Tags: java

// I can't have any doubles, only int. I'm getting the right result, but it possible to add a decimal? Instead of 150, I would like it to say 1.50. Thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class coinsInJar
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies, totalValue, totalValue2; 
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.print ("Enter the number of quarters: "); 
        quarters = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.print ("Enter the number of dimes: ");
        dimes = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.print ("Enter the number of nickels: "); 
        nickels = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.print ("Enter the number of pennies: "); 
        pennies = scan.nextInt();

        totalValue = (quarters * 25) + (dimes * 10) + (nickels * 5) + (pennies * 1);

        System.out.print ("Total value: $" + totalValue);

    }
}
```

Comment: @ccjmne _I can't have any doubles, only int._

Comment: Sorry, I guess I just didn't really understand the question... :)

Comment: @ccjmne - Have you read the question at least once???

Comment: Hint: You need to partially reverse the process after adding everything together. You need `dollars` and `cents`

Comment: Do you mean: `System.out.print ("Total value: $" + totalValue/100.0);` ?

Comment: @PM77-1 Do you mean you didn't read the question?

Comment: @BrianRoach If `double` prohibition extends to literals (not just variables), then you have a point.

Comment: @PM77-1 I suspect that was the point of the homework, yes. Otherwise, why not use a double all along.

Comment: @BrianRoach - then `Alexandru Grigoroy` gets the prize.

Comment: Thanks, double would've been so much easier, but it's required to use int. I added the code into my program and it seem to be working correctly for the most part. There's another problem that came up, but I'll try to figure it out on my own.

Answer (score 4):

Print the integer value, then the dot and then the rest:

```
System.out.print ("Total value: $" + totalValue/100 + "." + totalValue%100);
```

Comment: @PM77-1 To avoid floating point error. It's actually very clever. Note that `totalValue/100` leverages integer division, which truncates the decimal.

Comment: @PM77-1 And it fulfills the homework assignment of not using `double`. Though I think maybe just demonstrating modulo would have been better than doing their homework ;)